# Write a test that clicks on a date

Tags: jquery, codeception

My register view:

```
<div class="datepicker-days" style="display: block;">

<table class=" table-condensed">
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="old disabled day"></td>
            <td class="old disabled day"></td>
            <td class="old disabled day"></td>
            <td class="disabled day"></td>
            <td class="day">
                2
            </td>
```

I worte this test:

```
$I->click(['class' => 'day'],'2');
```

and received this error:

> Couldn't click {"class":"day"},"2": InvalidSelectorException: The
>   given selector 2 is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement.

Comment: Could you try to eleborate your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using some selector like this

```
"(//td[contains(@class,'day') and not(contains(@class,'disabled'))])[1]"
```

This selector is using XPath - it matches any td element, which has 'day' string in its class atribute but doesn't contain any 'disabled' string.

The number in the end [1] is order of element selected, when multiple elements match the selector. Starting at 1 (not zero).